# How do I fix TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, typeerror

this is the part of my code that brings up the issue.
it is for a keyword encryption code I am writing 
The keyword is the string of letters i am using too encrypt my message (a = 1 b = 2 etc) letter means each letter in the keyword.
The code works with one letter keywords and one letter messages to encrypt (keyword a + message to encrypt = b output is C) but keywords and messages to encrypt that are longer than one character bring up this issue.
keyword = (keyword[letter - 1])

Comment: Please provide more context in your questions. What is keyword, letter etc. can help others to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

problably your 'keyword' variable is turning into int type somewhere in your code, and even if that is the correct thing for your code, you have to turn in into string before performing a slice:

```
a = 1988
a[2] = TypeError

str(a)[2] = '8'  # yey
```

check if there isn't other ways to do what you pretend

Answer (score 0):

Looks like keyword is type int but you're treating it like string or list. Int objects don't have elements that can be accessed by indices.